# “The difficulty is we need” vs. “The difficulty is ᴛʜᴀᴛ we need”

Tags: noun-phrases, omissibility, predicative-complements

Is there a right or wrong answer in the following construction?  Am
I missing a more elegant way to say this?

1. The main difficulty in the hiring process is we need a fluent
   French speaker that also knows Mandarin.
2. The main difficulty in the hiring process is **that** we need a fluent
   French speaker that also knows Mandarin.

I can see how the *is that* seems more fluid at first, but I don’t
like slinging so much *is that* stuff around in my writing; and if
you speak this with the right cadence, *is* works just fine.

If *in the hiring process* is removed (or moved to the beginning
of the sentence), *is* seems to be the clear winner to my ear.

(Don’t ask why I want to know.  Let’s just say I now understand why
many writers don’t like editors.)

Comment: The connector *that* doesn't hurt the ear, it may help the reader, and it's very helpful for a coming translator or readers without native English.

Comment: I suppose that "The main difficulty in the hiring process is: we need a fluent French speaker that also knows Mandarin" would be preferable to some. I'd include the 'that'. But change the second 'that' to 'who'.

Comment: who also knows: who. :) The main HR issue is that we need etc. Finding people who speak French and Mandarin is not "a hiring process difficulty".

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that we're using a fully independent clause as a direct object. Let's try something really short on for size. "Your problem is you think too much." This seems to survive fine without the *that.*

If we invert it—"You think too much is your problem"—Well, then first of all we discover that inverting it ill-advised, but sometimes it helps us get a handle on what's going on. In this case, adding *that* would seem to help pull the clause together into one entity: "*That you think too much* is your problem." That's still a bizarre syntax, but the "that" seems to have helped matters. It also reveals that a more active rewrite might be an improvement: "Thinking too much is your problem."

Now, let's rashly perform reconstructive surgery on a much more complex sentence:

> "It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife."

First, let's spoil it by inverting it:

> "That a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife is a truth universally acknowledged."

Now, just to see what happens, let's lop of the "that":

> "A single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife is a truth universally acknowledged."

... Oh dear, what have we done.

In conclusion: Sometimes the "that" helps make the syntax clear. Sometimes a reorganization of the syntax is even better.

Answer (score 0):

“The main difficulty” of the original poster — as in many questions on this list — is an attempt to fit an idea into a rigid and unsuitable structure.

He has decided that the subject of his sentence will be “The difficulty in the hiring process”.  The fact that “the hiring process” is used rather than just “hiring” cries out for a need to reformulate the sentence in plain English.  Here as an example of how one might do so:

> “We have not been able to fill this position because it is difficult
> to find fluent French speakers who know Mandarin.”

Two ideas — situation and cause

- we can’t find someone for the job
- not many French speakers know Mandarin

Write each directly, joining with the conjunction, “because”. It’s ridiculous to talk about the “hiring process”.

**PS If you really want to make it “difficult”**

> Our difficulty is finding a fluent French speaker who also knows
> Mandarin.

Better to equate one noun — *difficulty* — with another (in effect) — *finding* — rather than with a verb form like “we need”.

Try writing with words containing no more than two syllables. To do this in my preferred solution we would have to replace “position” by “job” (or “post” if you must) and “difficult” by “hard”. “Mandarin”, however, defeats me. Sometimes you have to use three syllables, but the discipline is good fun.